# If else statement driven by current day of the week

Tags: r

I want to put an If statement together where the current day of the week is the decision criteria.  What do I use in R to determine the day of the week?

If today is Monday then ...
else if Tuesday then ...

Comment: Decision criteria for what? A date? A string?

Comment: Sorry I guess i'm having problems putting it into words. 
If the day of the week is Monday then run function A.

Comment: What do you want to compare to the days of the week?

Comment: Probably a combination of `Sys.Date()`, `weekdays`, and/or `format(...,format="%a")`.

Comment: I have two functions that get run.  If it is a Monday I run function A, If it is Tuesday through Friday I run function B.  I want to create an if statment that will detect the day of the week and use that to decide which function should be run.  I am  new to R and just don't know what the code is for figuring out what the day of the week is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current day:

```
currentDay <- weekdays(Sys.Date())
```

To use in an if statement

```
if (currentDay == 'Monday'){
  print('I hate Mondays')
} else if (currentDay == 'Tuesday'){
  print('I\'m in love')
}
```

Comment: Thank you DMR, weekdays(Sys.Date()) was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So the day you are running the code seems to be what you want, rather than a date in your dataset. Just get the current day, get the day of the week then you could do an if statement to run the appropriate code.

```
day <- weekdays(Sys.Date())
if (day == 'Monday') { ... }
else { ... }
```

etc